# Cakephp-3 how to filter data through pagination with has and belongs to many association?

Tags: filter, pagination, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-3.0

I have three tables Servers, Users and Groups. Servers has belongs to association with Users and HABTM association with Groups.
I get Servers with pagination like:

```
$this->paginate = [
        'limit' => 10,
        'contain' => ['Users', 'Groups'],
        'conditions' => [
            $conditions
        ]
    ];
$this->paginate($this->Servers);
```

I pass `$conditions` like username, server name and group name and they appear in the query as where fields.

Issue is, for `Groups` association, Cake creates separate query after the first query, which gets the Servers and associated Users. My conditions to filter through group name creates an error because group table is not joined in the first query which contains all my conditions, but in the second one that is created when i add `Groups` to `contain`.

Does anyone know how to create a filtering through HABTM associations with paginate or join all the tables in one query?